# PyCharm: Can't open two projects in the same window

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I am trying to open a second project in my current PyCharm window, and I got the following pop up window:

[image]

However, the choice of `"Add to currently opened project"` check box doesn't show.

The tutorial at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2018.1/opening-multiple-projects.html?utm_medium=link&utm_source=product&utm_campaign=PC&utm_content=2018.1 
has the check box. Why doesn't my pop-out window have the check box? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000488890-Missing-option-Add-to-currently-opened-projects-),
the option is only available for opening a new project. Also, see [the bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20579). In order to get the "add to currently opened projects" you have to go through "File" -> "Open" not "File" -> "Open Recent". Tested with PyCharm 2018.1 (Community Edition) on Windows 10.